# How to create dynamic form in google app maker?

Tags: google-app-maker

I want if I select a country from drop down, dynamically the states of that country should come in the drop down

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a "best way to do it". I know this site has a tutorial: https://appmakeruniversity.com/#/, unfortunately they charge like $20 per month. But they do have a free 14-day trial.

If I remember correctly, the method was basically creating two models (ModelA and ModelB), then doing a ONE to MANY relationship. Then having PanelA's datasource as (ModelA) then have PanelB's datasource = ModelB (relation).

Sorry, I know all that probably isn't super helpful.